# How to Aggregate Color Encoding in Vega-Lite Choropleth Map (geoshape) with a transform.lookup, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vega-lite

I'm trying to aggregate the color encoding in a vega-lite Choropleth map, using JavaScript.

[I have made a working example to make it easier to help and understand](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgBsABh1L4NMljQBWPUuQAnANZoQZOGwgwkOOIpBqkmFKlAMVoL2WLj4RLQQmNR0jEwMEHBWUHKYcLLRKQgETOlsbMaiAJymUAAcTGJqWgDMAGZaAOx1AIxlplp1amplLXC1OjVQWqZiolZIygRlcFAtXWpFLUx1K2JFjfUbdatlSKbeSFBMZXViNS1FOjMEjmwA+rmCtAwIUjLySnVsVsiYaKBMABPdz2TBsHBsaRyTx1OA+QIedDeXwgAC+aKU6RSahosjIAJAKUEP0JdRocEEansOCsEKSmApEEoshoEHuOI8SmBoPQAEcGEgMnQfDRSOiMUA)

The minimal code is:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 500,
  "mark": "geoshape",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benooghe/95c8b4d63f67f1856fdd81e6303c654e/raw/8ec1fdd91bfbf4973f97ffb8a5daacb8f431908e/geo_belgium.json",
    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "data"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "properties.nis_code", 
      "type": "quantitative", 
      // "aggregate":"sum"               // <-- THIS BREAKS THE MAP
    }
  }
}
```

This is a simplified version, it works, but if you add `, "aggregate: "sum"` in the encoding.color then it doesn't work anymore.

In case I oversimplified, my complete map is just a little bit more complicated: it has a `transform.lookup`.

```
  let yourVlSpec = {
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
    "width": 600,
    "height": 500,
    "mark": "geoshape",
    "data": { // TOPOJSON DATA -----
      "url": 'geo_belgium.json',
      "format": {
        "type": "topojson",
        "feature": "data"
      }
    },
    "transform": [{ // LEFT JOIN DATA -----
      "lookup": "properties.nis_code",
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "url": "data.csv"
        },
        "key": "NIS5",
        "fields": ["Cases", "Deaths"]
      }
    }],
    "encoding": {
      "color": {
        "field": "Cases",
        "type": "quantitative",
        // "aggregate": "sum"      // <-- THIS BREAKS THE MAP
      }
    }
  };
  vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
```

EDIT: I also tried this : in the `transform`

```
"aggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": 'Cases', "as": 'sum_cases'}],
```

EDIT2: The data in data.csv looks like this:

```
Date,PostCode,Cases,Deaths,NIS5
2020-04-08,2470,1,,13036
2020-04-08,2430,1,,13053
2020-04-08,1457,1,,25124
2020-04-08,3212,1,,24066
2020-04-08,2400,1,,13025
2020-04-08,1651,1,,23003
2020-04-08,2360,1,,13031
2020-04-07,1070,22,12,21004
2020-04-07,1070,22,12,21001
2020-04-07,4000,24,11,62093
2020-04-07,4000,24,11,62063
2020-04-01,9320,1,,41002
2020-04-01,7380,1,,53068
2020-04-01,9308,1,,41002
2020-03-31,1070,34,7,21004
2020-03-31,1070,34,7,21001
2020-03-31,3500,7,7,71022
2020-03-31,3800,10,5,71053
2020-03-31,4000,28,4,62063
2020-03-31,4000,28,4,62093
```

I'm looking to plot the sum of "Cases" per "NIS5", summing up all Dates

Answer (score 0):

When you express a sum as part of an encoding, it groups by all other encoding fields. In your case there are no other encoding fields, so it aggregates *everything* and throws-out the geometry.

One way to work around this is to add relevant fields to a `detail` encoding, so that the aggregation does not drop them from the data ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 500,
  "mark": "geoshape",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benooghe/95c8b4d63f67f1856fdd81e6303c654e/raw/8ec1fdd91bfbf4973f97ffb8a5daacb8f431908e/geo_belgium.json",
    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "data"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"field": "properties.nis_code", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "sum"},
    "detail": [{"field": "geometry", "type": "nominal"}, {"field": "properties.id", "type": "nominal"}, {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}]
  }
}
```

In your case, however, this is the same as the original unaggregated chart because there is a single `nis_code` per geographic area.

If you want to group by something other than geometric region, the best way to do that is to use a `joinaggregate` transform (which does not drop unnamed fields) and group by the particular data you're interested in grouping by. For example, here's the sum of `nis_code` grouped by the `level_2` feature ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 500,
  "mark": "geoshape",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benooghe/95c8b4d63f67f1856fdd81e6303c654e/raw/8ec1fdd91bfbf4973f97ffb8a5daacb8f431908e/geo_belgium.json",
    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "data"}
  },
  "transform" : [{
    "joinaggregate": [{"field": "properties.nis_code", "op": "sum", "as": "sum_nis_code"}],
    "groupby": ["properties.level_2"]
  }],
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"field": "sum_nis_code", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! How did you select the 3 things to put into `detail`? It doesn't seem to work with `transform.lookup`

Comment: I did a mistake posting the simplified without the transfer.lookup because I don't know how to apply this to my case. How can I both use `transfer.lookup` and the `joinaggregate`?

Comment: Trying this but somehow the sum doesn't add up all the dates ```"transform": [
          {
            "lookup": 'properties.nis_code',
            "from": {
              "data": {
                "url": 'data.csv'
              },
              "key": 'NIS5',
              "fields": ['Cases', 'Deaths']
            },
          },
          {
            "joinaggregate": [
              {"field": "Cases", "op": "sum", "as": "sum_Cases"}
            ],
            "groupby": ["properties.level_1"]
          }
        ],``` so it sum groups but not all the records in the data

Comment: Doing "max" it doesn't go above 5, it should be in the thousands. `{
            "joinaggregate": [
              {"field": "Cases", "op": "max", "as": "sum_Cases"}
            ],
            "groupby": ["properties.level_1"]
          }`